# What code should I paste into the HTML window of Wordpress to generate a large button which will randomly redirect to one of three websites?

Tags: html, wordpress, url, redirect, web

I'm using a basic Wordpress (or Google Sites) page to randomly redirect to one of three URLs. I'm not sure how to do this in HTML. The idea is to have a big button in the middle of the page which, on click, will send you to one of three links randomly. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You would not be able to fulfill this with ONLY HTML, you would need to use javascript to randomize the links and redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't do that only with html, you will need to do that with javascript.

You must store the links in an array and on click on the button call a function that randomly choose a link and go to it.

In the example below I only display the chosen link so you can click how many time you want to see the link change. Remove the line that do that and uncomment the line that make the redirection work.

```js
var locations = ['https://google.com', 'https://stackoverflow.com', 'https://bing.com'];    

document.getElementById("redirectButton").onclick = function () {
    var link = locations[Math.floor(Math.random() * locations.length)];
    
    // Remove this line 
    document.querySelector('.link').innerText = link; 
    
    // Uncomment this line
    // location.href = link;
};
```

```html
<button id="redirectButton">Random redirection</button>

<!-- You don't need that --> <p class="link"></p> <!-- Remove it on your site-->
```